# query effect not working if appended with parameters

Tags: jquery, parameters, effects

I have this code

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function MyFunc(obj,method){
    // obj.hide("slow"); // This part is working fine i.e. it is hiding the paragraph
    obj + "." + method + "(\"slow\")"; // This is not working

$(function(){
    $("#pid1").click(function(){
        MyFunc($("#pid1"),"hide");
    });
});

</script

</head>

<body>
<p id = "pid1">Test Paragraph</p>
</body>

</html>
```

i.e I want to pass the parameters to the jquery hide function and form the correct string to call the effect but it is not working as in the code above. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square brackets to access the property of an object with a string:

```
function MyFunc(obj, method) {
    obj[method]("slow"); 
}
```

Also note that you had missed the closing curly brace of `MyFunc`.

What you are currently doing is just producing a string, by concatenating a bunch of strings with an object. It won't throw an error, but it won't do anything whatsoever.

Comment: thanks a lot for quick reply !! The above is working fine. But what if we have other parameters are also there say the direction, the speed. How to form in that case ? Say i want to form this string obj.hide("blind",{direction:"vertical"},1000).

Comment: @niting112 - Have a read up on [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply)

Comment: Can you please tell what is the notation that you have used i.e obj[method]("slow"). Any documentation ?

Comment: @niting112 - You could [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators). It's just a way of accessing a property.